Keeping posts in Categories
I am a complete newbie in creating website. I chose WordPress to build up my blogging site so that I can start writing quickly. Somehow I have been able to create a basic free site. I have some writings which I want to keep in some 'categories'. I have created categories through the dashboard of 'WordPress.com' and has assigned one of my post in it. In the 'WP-ADMIN' dashboard it is acknoledged. But this category is not reflected in my site. How can I ensure that this category becomes visible in my site?

This stack is about WordPress (the software you download from wordpress.org and run on your own web hosting). Any issues with wordpress.com (the commercial blog host that uses a modified version of WordPress) are best addressed to their own support.
